# Using Linq building a Search query dealing with String.Empty

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I an trying to build a simple search LINQ statement. As the strings are passed into the WHERE, the empty strings are causing false results.

```
tmp = (from p in tmp
       where
           p.Customer.custEmail.Contains(filter.Email) &&
           p.Customer.custLastName.Contains(filter.LastName) &&
           p.orderID == id
       select p).ToList();
}
```

If the filter.LastName is empty, the query still tries to find the "", which results in NO RECORDS.

Without writing a bunch of

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.LastName))
```

for each Filter item, is there a way to do this **within the LINQ command**?

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL, Linq to Entities or Linq to Objects?  Please update tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the check to the where clause:

```
from p in tmp
where
    (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Email) && 
     p.Customer.custEmail.Contains(filter.Email)) &&
    (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.LastName) &&
     p.Customer.custLastName.Contains(filter.LastName)) &&
    p.orderID == id
select p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method for that:

```
public static bool ContainsIfNotNullOrWhiteSpace(this string source, string searched)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searched) ?
           false :
           source.Contains(searched);
}
```

Then you can use it in your query expression:

```
from p in tmp
where
    p.Customer.custEmail.ContainsIfNotNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Email) &&
    p.Customer.custLastName.ContainsIfNotNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.LastName) &&
    p.orderID == id
select p
```

Comment: If using LINQ to Objects, this would be fine. It would fall apart if using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework.